# Call Event on Controller after State Change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router for AngularJs. Here's a code snippet:

```
mc.Controller('usersControllerActions', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
    $scope.editedUser = null;    // This is set in my code (so it's not null)

    $scope.edit = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $state.go('users.edit');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('setUser', $scope.editedUser);
    }
});

mc.controller('usersControllerManager', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, global) {
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.$on('setUser', function (event, user) {
        $scope.user = user;
    }
}
```

Part of my routes:

```
    .state('users.edit', {
        views: {
            'manager@': {
                templateUrl: '/areas/users/manage',
                controller: 'usersControllerManager',
            }
        }
    })
```

My issue is the **first** time my route is called and the view is initialized, the `setUser` event is not called.  However, every subsequent time it runs fine.  It's almost like when the state changes the first time, the event hasn't had time to register itself.

I'm simply trying to pass a selected user to an edit form.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Is `$scope.editedUser` set asynchronously?

Comment: no, it is set in another method in my controller.

Comment: Could you include more of the code so we can see what is going on? It sounds like if the user is selected in a different view you could use $stateParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing users across multiple controllers, it might be better to create a service that handles which user is currently selected/being edited. This way you avoid the issue of running into cases where the next controller hasn't been instantiated yet. Services are singletons, so they will not have this race condition.

So, instead of using $rootScope.broadcast(), you could use:

```
// do stuff     
myUserService.setEditedUser(editedUser);
$state.go()

----
// set user in other controller
$scope.user = myUserService.getEditedUser();
```

Comment: that's what i ended up doing, but my concern is that in large applications creating a bunch of singletons could create a potential memory leak of sorts.

Comment: This is the way I've seen it done for most angular applications when it comes to handling users and updates, so I wouldn't be too concerned.

Comment: Singletons.... memory leak... you realize memory leaks come from creating and destroying instances of objects and the computer not giving all the memory back on destroy. Sooo that's just backwords to begin with, and also JS's garbage collection is impeccable and never dirty unless you personally muck it up with streams in NodeJS...